# Is it possible to use multiple levels of aggregation in a single Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've written a Cypher query to find the product of the inverse node degrees for all paths between a given source and target. I'd like to also be able to include the percent of the total that each path would represent if the inverse node degrees were all summed together. However, when I create this sum in a WITH statement (seen below), the percent returned is always 100.

```
MATCH path = (n0:Compound)-[:BINDS_CbG]-(n1)-[:PARTICIPATES_GpPW]-(n4:Disease)
WHERE n0.identifier = "DB01156"
AND n4.identifier = "DOID:0050742"
WITH
[
...
] AS degrees, path

// Adding a second with query allows us to access PDP for creating the PERCENT_OF_DWPC field in the return
WITH degrees, path, reduce(pdp = 1.0, d in degrees| pdp * d ^ -1) AS PDP
WITH path, PDP, sum(PDP) AS DWPC
RETURN
path,
PDP,
100 * (PDP / DWPC) AS PERCENT_OF_DWPC

ORDER BY PERCENT_OF_DWPC DESC
```

I know it is possible to do this by effectively writing the query twice (seen below), but it then takes twice as long to run. Is it possible to forgo the extra overhead and calculate the percentage in a WITH clause?

```
MATCH path = (n0:Compound)-[:BINDS_CbG]-(n1)-[:PARTICIPATES_GpPW]-(n4:Disease)
WHERE n0.identifier = "DB01156"
AND n4.identifier = "DOID:0050742"
WITH
[
...
] AS degrees, path

WITH sum(reduce(pdp = 1.0, d in degrees| pdp * d ^ -0.4)) AS DWPC

MATCH path = (n0:Compound)-[:BINDS_CbG]-(n1)-[:PARTICIPATES_GpPW]-(n4:Disease)
WHERE n0.identifier = "DB01156"
AND n4.identifier = "DOID:0050742"
WITH
[
...
] AS degrees, path, DWPC

WITH path, DWPC, reduce(pdp = 1.0, d in degrees| pdp * d ^ -0.4) AS PDP
RETURN
path,
PDP,
100 * (PDP / DWPC) AS PERCENT_OF_DWPC

ORDER BY PERCENT_OF_DWPC DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace this snippet:

```
WITH path, PDP, sum(PDP) AS DWPC
RETURN
  path,
  PDP,
  100 * (PDP / DWPC) AS PERCENT_OF_DWPC
ORDER BY PERCENT_OF_DWPC DESC
```

with this:

```
WITH path, collect(PDP) AS pdps, sum(PDP) AS DWPC
UNWIND pdps AS PDP
RETURN
  path,
  PDP,
  100 * (tofloat(PDP) / DWPC) AS PERCENT_OF_DWPC
ORDER BY PERCENT_OF_DWPC DESC
```

The original `WITH` clause has 2 "grouping keys", `path` and `PDP`, so the `sum()` [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating) would sum over distinct `path` and `PDP` pairs (in other words, it would only use one `PDP` in each sum), which is not what you intended.

The new `WITH` clause adds the use of the aggregating function `collect()` to collect all the `PDP` values. Since this new clause now has only a single non-aggregating term, `path`, that term is used as the entire grouping key (for both functions). This causes the `sum()` function to actually sum over *all* `PDP` values for the same `path`. The `UNWIND` clause is then used to separate back out the individual `PDP` values. Also, I assume that `PDP` is an integer, so the `tofloat()` function is used to ensure that the division does not perform integer truncation.

[UPDATE]

If you actually need the sum, `DWPC`, to be calculated over *all* `path` values, then the new code snippet needs to be a bit more complex:

```
WITH path, collect(PDP) AS pdps, sum(PDP) AS sum1
WITH collect({path: path, pdps: pdps}) AS allData, sum(sum1) AS DWPC
UNWIND allData AS data
UNWIND data.pdps AS PDP
RETURN
  data.path AS path,
  PDP,
  100 * (tofloat(PDP) / DWPC) AS PERCENT_OF_DWPC
ORDER BY PERCENT_OF_DWPC DESC
```

Comment: DWPC (Degree weighted path count) is supposed to be a sum of PDP (the path degree product) for all paths, so the using path as a grouping key causes the percent to always be 100. Is it possible to force path to not be used as the grouping key?